# How can I get the seed of a numpy `Generator`?

Tags: python, numpy, random

I am using `rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=None)` for testing purposes following [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generator.html#numpy.random.default_rng).

My program is a scientific code, so it is good to have some random values to test it, but if I found a problem with the code's result, I would like to get the seed back and try again to find the problem. Is there any way to do that?

Things like this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32172054/how-can-i-retrieve-the-current-seed-of-numpys-random-number-generator) does not seem to work with a `Generator`:

> AttributeError: 'numpy.random._generator.Generator' object has no attribute 'get_state'

Of course I can always try a set of predefined seeds, but that is not what I want.

Comment: *if I found a problem with the code's result* - did that happen already? If yes, does it happen all the time?

Comment: @tevemadar there has not been any problem with the code's result. But knowing the seed is required for reproducibility if that would be the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `__getstate__`, `__setstate__` and forget about `seed`... it's just a parameter for `default_rng`!

```
# old instance
rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=None)
s_old = rng.__getstate__()

# new instance
rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=123123) # seed=anything, also None
s_new = rng.__getstate__()
print(s_old == s_new)
#False

# update "seed"
rng.__setstate__(s_old) # pass the old "seed"
s_recovered = rng.__getstate__()
print(s_old == s_recovered)
#True
```

Then when you call methods to generate random numbers you will be able to replicate the randomness.

---

Alternative of the *dunder* methods

```
# get the state
s_old = rng.bit_generator.state
```

and

```
# set the state of the new instance of rng
rng.bit_generator.state = s_old
```

Comment: Your solution works, but in my opinion it has a drawback, the use of `__getstate__` and `__setstate__`, I do not think they are supposed to be used outside the class itself. That is something I would try to avoid.

Comment: maybe [useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32679403/python-dangers-of-temporarily-changing-the-random-seed-using-a-context-manager)

Comment: Yes, if you know what you are doing, there is not problem with your solution, but I still think that it is better to avoid these methods (just personal preference).

Answer (score 3):

I don't remember if there is a method to get the seed directly. But alternatively you can generate a random number first, print it in logs and then set that number as seed for the rest of the program.

Comment: That is a good idea, although the `Generator` does not have a function `set_seed` or similar, so you need two `Generator`s for that.

Comment: @Abel Gutiérrez don't use `seed=None` but a pass any number to it and keep track of it as if it were the **key** used to generate your results

Comment: @cards `seed=None`  was written to play with some seeds not decided by me. The idea is to use any seed and if something went wrong, look at the seed.

Comment: @cards I need some minutes to read and evaluate it...